# react-select keep the clearindicator visiable after clear?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

react-select how to keep the ClearIndicator visible after clear， I custom the selector ClearIndicator to a down arrow in default, and when hover, it will be a cross, after click cross,I want to keep the indicator still visible, what should I to do to keep it?

Answer (score 0):

When isClearable is false, or when isMulti is false, and isClearable is undefined. So, for this pass the isClearable true if you wanna keep it.